# Explain Pigeon holes principle in your own words.

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

my own words explanation: If there is four pigeonholes in which six pigeons uses to lay their eggs, then there is atleast one pigeonhole housing two or more pigeons.

Does my wordings correct and relevant?

Comment: Only need 5 pigeons. Relevant to what?

Comment: @Karl,yeap it should only be 5 pigeons thanks for spoting that. I meant relevant to the Pigeon hole principle.

Comment: Yes it is correct. If there are more pigeons than pigeon holes they need to share. It is used to show things like there are at least two people with the same number of hairs on their head given the number of people exceeds the number of hairs on a head.

Comment: I'm going to be the negative Nellie and say that is an example and not an explanation.  (Although it's a very good example that demonstrates why we call it "the pigeonhole principal"-- but it's not an explaination.)

Comment: Why the downvote?  It's a very relevent question and the OP expressed thought

Comment: I think giving an example clearly explain the principle, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun wording with relevance overflowing:

Suppose we have $n$ bodies to hide,  but only $n-1$ small flower gardens to hide the bodies in.  We would need to fit two bodies in a garden,  but small flower gardens clearly only house a single body, so we're screwed.

Answer (score 0):

I m a student and a perfect example.

We are $4$ best friends and do our lunch together always. Let's say one day I forgot to bring my lunch box. Now being friends, my 3 other friends had to show their friendship and hence they offered me to hare their lunch.

Now the scenario is that there are $4$ students and $3$ lunch boxes. So, I will be sharing lunch with either of $3$ who bring their lunch box. Ultimately you can say that there will be at least $1$ lunch box which will be shared.

Now the problem is not till now. It is possible that all $4$ of us only share the one lunch box and other two remain unopened but in this case too we will have a lunch box being shared. (Remember the term at least).